# wpf toolkit from nuget, more binaries than I care about

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, wpftoolkit, nuget-package

If I install "Extended WPF Toolkit" from nuget via the Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio, it downloads and references these 6 dlls:

Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock

Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Themes.Aero

Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Themes.Metro

Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Themes.VS2010

Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid

Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit

I am only interested in the Toolkit itself, not the DataGrid or AvalonDock.  If I remove these dll references from my projects, will I maintain the benefits of using the nuget package manager?  Or will it break the functionality of the package manager for this package?

Comment: I'd rather not make any assumptions and create headaches for future developers

Comment: I agree don't assume - test.  Did you test?

Comment: I've removed the references, and the nuget package manager still believes it is installed correctly.  I'm not sure if it will cause any issue if/when the package needs updating, however.

Comment: If a required DLL is missing it will let you know.  I always just add the one(s) I am using.